# Get the actual angle after the superview is rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotatetransform

I have 5 subviews(White) added to the superview(Gray), when I rotate the superview I want to know the angle(like 1 and 2) of each of the subview with the red circle.(the center of the subviews and the red circle are ON the same circle)

**Start Position:**
[image]

**Rotated Position:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to provide more information as surely angle of A is just the amount of the rotation and the angle of E is always 72 degrees before it?

Comment: Thanks for replying, angle AOE is exactly 360 / 5 = 72 degree. As the gray view is rotated angle 1 (angle 1 could be any -180 ~ 180 degree), I need to know the position of point A(A is center point of this subview) and other points like B, C, D and E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment you appear to want to determine the coordinates of the centres of your five circles for a given rotation. The centres will all lie on a circle. So your question boils down to what are the coordinates of a point on a circle of radius *r* for an angle *θ*. The parametric equations for a circle give you that:

> *x* = *r* cos *θ*
>
> *y* = *r* sin *θ*

The angle, *θ*, in these equations is measured in *radians* from the positive x-axis in an anti-clockwise direction. If your angle are in degrees you will find the `M_PI` constant for *π* useful as:

> 360 degrees = 2 *π* radians

The rest is simple math, take your angle of rotation to give you the angle for A (remembering to adjust for 0 being the x-axis and measuring anti-clockwise if needed), the other centres are multiples of 72 degrees (0.4 *π* radians) from this.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if you just need to take a known point and rotate it a certain number of degrees, check out the docs for [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1666405-cgaffinetransform?language=objc).

For example:

```
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle);
CGPoint rotatedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform (startingPoint, rotation);
```

This rotation matrix is around (0, 0) and the angle is in radians, so you will need to subtract the center of your superview's bounds to get an offset relative to the center, do the rotation, and add back in the center. Or you can build an affine transform made up of that translation, rotation, and inverse translation, and then apply that to your starting point as above.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already seem to know the main rotation angle, this will give you the angles in the range -180 .. +180 and positions of each of the white discs:

```
GCFloat toRads = M_PI / 180.0;

CGFloat angleA = self.rotationInDegrees;
if (angleA > 180) angleA -= 360;
CGFloat xA = self.radius * sinf(angleA * toRads);
CGFloat yA = self.radius * cosf(angleA * toRads);

CGFloat angleB = angleA + 72;
if (angleB > 180) angleB -= 360;
CGFloat xB = self.radius * sinf(angleB * toRads);
CGFloat yB = self.radius * cosf(angleB * toRads);

etc...
```

(This assumes your zero degrees is from the vertical. If it's from the horizontal swap cos and sin over).